# Friendly target identification in radar

Tags: radar, tracking, signal-identification

How do radar systems identify friendly targets to avoid AA locks during combat scenarios?

Do friendly planes broadcast a known signal or is something else going on?

Answer (score 2):

Every system will be different, so it’s impossible to make a blanket statement that applies to everything, but [IFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identification_friend_or_foe?wprov=sfti1) systems can be used to accomplish the task. The signal processing here can be as basic as looking for a predetermined pulse pattern, or require demodulation/decryption of some “special” signal. The Wikipedia article I linked covers the topic in pretty great detail.